# Showing that the following are equivalent by a proper route.

Tags: measure-theory, definition, lebesgue-measure, alternative-proof

$A\subset \mathbb R$ is said to be Lebesgue measurable if for each $E\subset \mathbb R$,$m^*(E)=m^*(E\cap A)+m^*(E\cap A^c)$ where $m^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.Now I have to prove that the following are equivalent:

$1. A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

$2.\exists $a Borel set $B\subset A$ such that $m^*(A-B)=0$.

$3. $For each $\epsilon>0$ there exists a closed set $F_\epsilon\subset A$ such that $m^*(A-F_\epsilon)<\epsilon$.

$4.\exists $ open sets $G_1,G_2,...\supset A$ such that $m^*(\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty G_n-A)=0$.

$5.$There exist closed ets $F_1,F_2,...\subset A$ such that $m^*(A-\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty F_n)=0$.

$6.$ There exists a Borel set $B\supset A$ such that $m^*(B-A)=0$.

$7.$ For each $\epsilon>0$ there exists an open set $G_\epsilon\supset A$  such that $m^*(G_\epsilon-A)<\epsilon$.

I could prove the following implications $(1)\implies (7)\implies (6)$ and $(3)\implies (5)\implies (2)$ and $(7)\implies (4)\implies (6)$ but I am having problem with the others.

Can someone show me a proper route so that I can prove that all of these are equivalent?Also,as I am a beginner,can someone show me how to prove those implications?

**Addendum**

I had asked one question earlier but that did not show me all these are equivalent.

Comment: If $A$ is Lebesgue measurable, then so is $A^c$ [can you see why?].  What happens if you apply $(1) \implies (7)$ with $A^c$ in place of $A$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Please explain what will happen?I think you are making mistake somewhere.

Comment: "Please explain what will happen?" - It gives a proof of $(1)\implies (3)$.  "I think you are making mistake somewhere" - I'm not even sure what you're talking about, especially after seemingly not even attempting to follow the hint.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Sorry now I understood the point.We have to note that $G_\epsilon-A^c=A-G_\epsilon^c$

Comment: But what about the other implications

Comment: I have to find the shortest route of showing these are equivalent.I cannot just go on proving arbitrarily $^7P_2$ many implications

Comment: Have you already proven Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable using your definition?  If so, showing $(6) \implies (1)$ is not hard, and then if you understand my initial hint, you're finished.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have proved that Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you have shown $(1) \implies (7) \implies (4) \implies (6)$.  To finish, it will suffice to show $(6) \implies (1)$ and then relate the remaining statements to these by taking complements.

---

Here is a proof of $(6) \implies (1)$:

Suppose $B$ is a Borel set such that $B \supset A$ and $m^*(B \setminus A) = 0$, and let $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ denote any set.  Since Borel sets are Lebesgue measurable,
$$m^*(E) = m^*(E \cap B) + m^*(E \cap B^c) \\
m^*(E\cap A^c) = m^*(E\cap A^c\cap B) + m^*(E\cap A^c\cap B^c)$$
Considering the second of these equations, we note
$$E\cap A^c \cap B^c = E\cap B^c \\
E\cap A^c \cap B \subset B\setminus A \implies m^*(E\cap A^c \cap B) = 0,$$
so that $$m^*(E\cap A^c) = m^*(E\cap A^c\cap B) + m^*(E\cap A^c\cap B^c) = m^*(E\cap B^c).$$
Additionally, since
$$E\cap A \subset E\cap B \subset (E\cap A)\cup (B \setminus A) \implies m^*(E\cap A) \leq m^*(E\cap B) \leq m^*(E\cap A) + m^*(B\setminus A),$$
we have that $m^*(E\cap A) = m^*(E\cap B).$
Putting it together,
$$m^*(E) = m^*(E\cap B) + m^*(E\cap B^c) = m^*(E\cap A) + m^*(E\cap A^c),$$
and since $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ was arbitrary, $A$ is Lebesgue measurable.

---

Combined with what you'd already shown, this shows $(1), (4), (6), (7)$ are equivalent statements.  Now, instead of writing separate proofs for the equivalence of the others, we use the fact that $(1)$ is equivalent [which is nearly obvious by your definition] to
$$(1^c) \quad A^c \text{ is Lebesgue measurable}$$

By the equivalence of $(1), (4), (6), (7)$, it follows that $(1^c)$ is equivalent to each of $(4^c), (6^c), (7^c)$ where $(n^c)$ is the result of replacing $A$ by $A^c$ in $(n)$.  By DeMorgan's laws, the duality between open/closed sets, and the fact the Borel sets are closed under complements, we can identify $(4^c)$ with $(5)$, $(6^c)$ with $(2)$, and $(7^c)$ with $(3)$.

In doing this, we conclude $(1)-(7)$ are equivalent statements.

Comment: Please explain why $E\cap A\subset E\cap B\subset (E\cap A)\cup (B-A)$.

Comment: @KishalaySarkar The first inclusion requires $A \subset B$ as assumed in (6).  The second inclusion always holds as a result of $B \subset A \cup (B\setminus A)$.